# Using timestamp of a particular command in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I'm trying to use the timestamps of a particular command I ran previously. Running something along the lines of `history 10 | grep "keyword"` gives me the output in the command line (my history preferences are set up to include a timestamps), but I can't actually figure out how to utilize this information in a script.

Is there any way to use this or another way to get the timestamps from a particular command? I'm trying to determine the last time a `command` was run, and if it was longer than a specific amount of time, run it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used the timestamp format in history as

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
```

then you can use this command

```
history | grep ls  | grep -v grep | tail -1 | awk '{print $2,$3;}'
```

NOTE: I am searching for command **ls** and i am printing the timestamp of the command **ls** when it was last used